# Ansible equivalent of below sed command

Tags: ansible

How can i use ansible lineinfile module to simulate working of below sed command.

```
sed -i _bkp '/(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.0.0.1)(PORT = 1501))/d;s/(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.0.0.2)(PORT = 1501))/(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = my-site.com)(PORT = 1501))/;/(BALANCE = yes))/d' myconffile
```

Comment: Wouldn't be better to use `'/AAA/d;s/BBB/CCC/;/DDD/d'` ?

Comment: @VladimirBotka : These lines are part of a config file.I was looking for a similar implementation in ansible using lineinfile/replace module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace all lines in the file [replace](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/replace_module.html#replace-replace-all-instances-of-a-particular-string-in-a-file-using-a-back-referenced-regular-expression) module is needed. This is the equivalent (backup differs).

```
  tasks:
    - lineinfile:
        path: myconffile
        backup: yes
        state: absent
        regexp: '\(ADDRESS = \(PROTOCOL = TCP\)\(HOST = 10.0.0.1\)\(PORT = 1501\)\)'
    - replace:
        path: myconffile
        backup: yes
        regexp: '\(ADDRESS = \(PROTOCOL = TCP\)\(HOST = 10.0.0.2\)\(PORT = 1501\)\)'
        replace: '(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = my-site.com)(PORT = 1501))'
    - lineinfile:
        path: myconffile
        backup: yes
        state: absent
        regexp: '\(BALANCE = yes\)'
```

The simplified version is below.

```
  tasks:
    - lineinfile:
        path: myconffile
        backup: yes
        state: absent
        regexp: "{{ item }}"
      loop:
        - 'AAA'
        - 'DDD'
    - replace:
        path: myconffile
        backup: yes
        regexp: 'BBB'
        replace: 'CCC'
```